# Function always returns empty list

Tags: python

This is a code for finding three numbers such that their sum is zero, from a given array. I have looked at this multiple times and also debugged it but still can't find whats the issue. The output is always an empty list (even though there is value present in the variable res during debugging)

```
def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    res = set()
    for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
        if idx > len(nums) - 3:
            return
        
        i = idx+1
        j = len(nums) - 1
        
        while i < j:
            s = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[idx]
            if s == 0:
                res.add((nums[i], nums[j], nums[idx]))
                i += 1
                j -= 1
            elif s < 0:
                j-=1
            else:
                i+=1
        
    return list(res)
```

Comment: is your list length  less then 3 ?

Comment: `if idx > len(nums) - 3: return` will return an empty result.

Comment: That `return` should be `break`

Comment: Even if it *always* fails, it would still be helpful to give us a call demonstrating it.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't return an empty list, though.

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()`? You never use `num`. Just do `for i in range(len(nums)-3):`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I'll bet they're confusing `None` with an empty list.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I bet it's [at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/), which displays a `None` result as `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `idx > len(nums)` will always be true at the end of the day. It should be `break` not `return` as someone said in the comment.